Loki and Grafana: Show the last log line for each label
I have a number applications that log their current version. Now I have these lines stored in Loki with the following structure:



Timestamp
Labels
Line




2024-06-10
{version_report=1, app=AppFoo}
v1.0


2024-06-05
{version_report=1, app=AppBar}
24.1.0


2024-06-06
{version_report=1, app=AppBar}
24.1.1


2024-06-07
{version_report=1, app=AppBar}
24.1.2


2024-06-05
{version_report=1, app=AppBaz}
Alpha


2024-06-10
{version_report=1, app=AppBaz}
Beta



I'd like to create a Grafana dashboard that shows the last entry for each app-Label in a table, effectively giving me an overview what version has been running lately:



App
Version




AppFoo
v1.0


AppBar
24.1.2


AppBaz
Beta



I've already experimented with different LogQL-queries and also restructuring the results with transformators. But in the end I cannot get the end-result I'd like to have. Is there a way to do it?

did you figure this out? I also need to do something similar; get the last value grouped by a set of labels based on a timestamp

Nope, I'm currently looking into a different solution to achieve what I need. Bummer though, my scenario is not the only one I can think of where this would be useful.
